# Has the setting to disable icon frames been removed on the Galaxy S10 lineup?

Tags: 9.0-pie, app-icons, samsung-galaxy-s-10

On previous versions of Samsung Galaxy phones I've owned, I had the option to enable/disable icon frames around the apps on my home screen. This setting could be found by navigating to **Settings > Display > Home Screen > Icon Badges**.

After digging around the settings of my Galaxy S10+, I have not been able to find such a feature.  Has this setting been removed with the launch of The S10 and One UI?

Below is a screenshot of the setting I'm referring to from my Galaxy Note 8:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a setting that started in Oreo related to [Adaptive Icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive).  You now need specific themes to remove the border.

Per the following link:

> If you don't want borders, go to settings>wallpaper and
>   themes>icons>download and find an icon pack with no borders.

https://androidforums.com/threads/why-is-there-no-option-to-remove-icon-frame-borders-on-the-new-android-pie-update.1295501/

Answer (score 4):

I read from many posts that the option shown above has been removed. Only solution I found is to download an icons set that was made without frames feature.  I am using one called Zero made by MINU after seeing its link in another post about the same issue on this website.